# text all display's at once?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I have some JLabels for my updater, everything runs smoothly except for the text.

The text is all scrambled & looks likes it all being displayed at once. I've tried setting each text as it's own label & setting the ones that are irrelevant when the method is called to opaque. But I get nullpointerexceptions. I've also tried layering my JFrame butthen it get's rid of my JProgrssbar?

Here's my code:

```
public static void displayText(int Stage) {
    String txt = "";
    if (Stage == 1) {
        txt = "Checking Cache...";
    } 
    if (Stage == 2) {
        txt = "Downloading Cache...";
    }
    if (Stage == 3) {
        txt = "Cache Download Complete!";
    }
    if (Stage == 4) {
        txt = "Unpacking Files...";
    } 
    if (Stage == 5) {
        txt = "Launching Client!";
    }
    lbl = new JLabel();
    lbl.setText(txt);
    lbl.setBounds(137, 11, 200, 14);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lbl);
}
```

I've tried reformatting it in a few different ways & still does the same thing...

An example of what it's doing:
[image]

Comment: Show the rest of your code please. Also, why are you creating a new label for every invocation?

Comment: Just remove `lbl = new JLabel();` you needn't to create a new `JLabel` every time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're creating a new label each time and placing it atop the old. Declare the label somewhere in the scope of your class (a more descriptive name would be good too). Then, in your method, only call lbl.setText(txt). This will update the pre-existing label with the updated text.

It should look something like this:

```
public class yourGUI {
    private JLabel progressLabel;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       progressLabel = new JLabel();
       progressLabel.setBounds(137, 11, 200, 14);
       frame.getContentPane().add(progressLabel);
    }

    public static void displayText(int Stage) {
        String txt = "";
        if (Stage == 1) {
            txt = "Checking Cache...";
        } else if (Stage == 2) {
            txt = "Downloading Cache...";
        } else if (Stage == 3) {
            txt = "Cache Download Complete!";
        } else if (Stage == 4) {
            txt = "Unpacking Files...";
        } else {  //assuming (Stage == 5), this is up to your discretion 
            txt = "Launching Client!";
        }
        progressLabel.setText(txt);
    }
}
```

Also, no need to check each if statement every time.

Comment: Hey Turbo Thank you. As the for the if instead of else if I was just trying something & forgot to change it back.